# joining multiple tables and returning a zero if not row in one

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to setup a new permissions database in MySQL and I'm breaking my brain over something that I'm sure is very simple. I'm certain something to this tune has been answered here before but after hours of searching I have found nothing that works.

I have 4 tables that are relevant

Permission (contains every possible permission)

```
|permission_name | description |
--------------------------------
|users.list      | etc. etc.   |
|users.update    | etc. etc.   |
|users.delete    | etc. etc.   |
```

User

```
| id      | fname | group_id |
------------------------------
| 1       | John  | 1        |
| 2       | Nancy | 1        |
| 3       | Paul  | 2        |
```

Group

```
| group_id | group_name |
-------------------------
| 1        | Webmasters |
| 2        | Corporate  |
| 3        | HR         |
```

Group_permission (contains permissions relevant to each group)

```
| group_id | permission_name | permission_type (1=Y|0=not set|-1=N)
----------------------------------------------
| 1        | users.list      | 1              |
| 1        | users.update    | 1              |
| 2        | users.list      | 1              |
```

OK so lots of relations going on, but I'm trying to get ALL the group permissions for a specific user EVEN if the group permission doesn't exist yet.

I imagined this being some sort of left join using a permission table as a base, but whenever I include the WHERE user.id = 2 it limits my result set down and won't include nulls on the right side.

```
SELECT a.permission_name, IFNULL(b.permission_type, 0)
FROM permission a
LEFT JOIN group_permission b on b.permission_name = a.permission_name
LEFT JOIN user c on c.group_id = b.group_id
WHERE c.id = 2
```

the result I want to see for Nancy is

```
|permission_name | permission_type |
------------------------------------
|users.list      | 1               |
|users.update    | 0               |
|users.delete    | 0               |
```

I won't know what group the user is in on the PHP side, so I have to query by using the users ID only.

All I'm getting is

```
|permission_name | permission_type |
------------------------------------
|users.list      | 1               |
```

Any help appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being just a subquery that did the trick.

```
SELECT a.permission_name, IFNULL(b.permission_type, 0)
FROM permission a
NATURAL LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT a.group_id, a.permission_name, a.permission_type FROM group_permission a
    NATURAL LEFT JOIN users b
    WHERE b.id = 2
) as b
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure that this will work, but try joining the group_permissions table to the permissions table.

```
SELECT a.permission_name, IFNULL(b.permission_type, 0)
FROM group_permission a
LEFT JOIN permission b on a.permission_name = b.permission_name
LEFT JOIN user c on c.group_id = b.group_id
WHERE c.id = 2
```